# Is the issue that my questions are vulgar or that they are difficult?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Here's an example

[Does the existence of eudemonia today depend on a certain level of wealth or monetary income?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95020/does-the-existence-of-eudemonia-today-depend-on-a-certain-level-of-wealth-or-mon)

It is vulgar, we're all interested in what the answer is, but then the "answer" is difficult to find. I couldn't find a philosopher who directly tackles the question anyway.

Isn't that the point of this site?

Comment: Your question about eudaimonia is perfectly proper. It is answered by Aristotle, Nicomachean Ethics, I.8, 1099a-b, where he says that it 'evidently also needs external goods to be added [to virtuous activity] ... since we cannot, or cannot easily, do fine actions if we lack the resources. For, first of all, in many actions we use friends, *wealth*, and political power just as we use instruments.' Aristotle, Nicomachean Ethics, tr. T. Irwin, 2nd ed., Indianapolis: Hackett, 1999: 11.)

Comment: hey thanks @GeoffreyThomas